# Recognize the user input inside the handler function using dialogflow.ai/api.ai and Microsoft Bot Builder

Tags: botframework, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I am building a bot using the given technology stacks:

1. Microsoft Bot Builder
2. Node.js
3. Dialogflow.ai (api.ai)

We used waterfall model to implement a matched intent Dialog, which includes a couple of handler functions and prompts. After following this scenario I need to identify the entities inside an inner handler function, for a user input.

eg:

Bot : Where do you want to fly?

User: Singapore. (For this we added entities like SIN - Singapore,SIN(Synonym), So I need to resolve the value as SIN)

Any help on this scenario is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post [Using api.ai with microsoft bot framework](https://medium.com/@akshaykulkarni/using-api-ai-with-microsoft-bot-framework-577a5d9fb66f) you can refer for your reqirement, and with a sample at https://github.com/GanadiniAkshay/weatherBot/blob/master/api.ai/index.js. The weather api key leveraged in this sample is out of date, but the waterfall and recognizer api key is still working.

Generally speaking:

- Use [`api-ai-recognizer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/api-ai-recognizer)
- Instantiate the `apiairecognizer` and leveraged `builder.IntentDialog` to include the `recognizer`:

  ```
   var recognizer = new apiairecognizer("<api_key>");
   var intents = new builder.IntentDialog({
       recognizers: [recognizer]
   });
  ```
- In `IntentDialog`s, use `builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities,'<entity>');` to recognize the intent entities.

Comment: How can find the entities after an inner promt from the next handler function. intent.matches('intent-name', [function (session, args, results) { var entity_foumd=builder.Entityrecognizer.findEntiy....promt for text input},function (session, results) { inside this handler we will get the user input, if this prompt result contains any of the entity, we have to find that entity value }]...my question is how can I find intent from second handler function.

Comment: if you have a missing field and api.ai fires a prompt for it with actionIncomplete = true how do you handle this prompt in api ai recognizer